# How to collect a specific value from a text that is always a few lines below another text value?

Tags: python, json

To retrieve the values from the JSON file, I use this code:

```
import json

json_file = json.load(open('Bla_Bla_Bla.json'))

master_data = json_file['messages']

for unique_message in master_data:
    print(unique_message['text'])
```

This is the JSON template:

```
{
 "name": "Bla Bla Bla",
 "type": "public_channel",
 "id": 123456789,
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": 12460,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2022-02-07T04:14:51",
   "from": "Bla Bla Bla",
   "from_id": "channel1127646148",
   "text": "Yesterday's Tips\n   \n   First Half\n   Tips: 2\n   Win/Loss: 0/2\n   Void: 0\n   Win Ratio: 0%\n   Invested: 2u\n   Net Profit: -2u\n   ROI: -100%\n   \n   Second Half\n   Tips: 10\n   Win/Loss: 4/4\n   Void: 2\n   Win Ratio: 40%\n   Invested: 8u\n   Net Profit: 1.145u\n   ROI: 14.3%\n   \n   Total\n   Tips: 12\n   Win/Loss: 4/6\n   Void: 2\n   Win Ratio: 33.3%\n   Invested: 10u\n   Net Profit: -0.855u\n   ROI: -8.6%\n   \n   Highest Odds won: 2.500"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is the output text:

```
Yesterday's Tips
   
   First Half
   Tips: 2
   Win/Loss: 0/2
   Void: 0
   Win Ratio: 0%
   Invested: 2u
   Net Profit: -2u
   ROI: -100%

   Second Half
   Tips: 10
   Win/Loss: 4/4
   Void: 2
   Win Ratio: 40%
   Invested: 8u
   Net Profit: 1.145u
   ROI: 14.3%

   Total
   Tips: 12
   Win/Loss: 4/6
   Void: 2
   Win Ratio: 33.3%
   Invested: 10u
   Net Profit: -0.855u
   ROI: -8.6%

   Highest Odds won: 2.500
```

I'm trying to collect the value to `Net Profit:` that is inserted inside `Total`, the texts can change and the positions too, but whenever there is a `Total`, there will be a `Net Profit:`.

The value I want to collect in this case is:

```
-0.855u
```

How can I go about getting that specific part of the text value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex cases, you may want to look into Regular Expressions (Regex), but for this simple case:

```py
string = unique_message["text"]  # the json data

string = string[string.find("Total"):]  # cut all the part before "Total"
string = string[string.find("Net Profit") + 12:]   # cut all the part before "Net Profit" (the + 12 removes the Net Profit bit too)
string = string[:string.find("\n")]  # take the part of the string till the next line
print(string)
```

Here, we use the `str.find()` function which returns the index of a certain part of a string together with string slicing `string[start:end]` to find only the part of the string needed. The `\n` is a special character which denotes the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Net Profit: -0.855u` is always after the `Total`, you can first find the index of `Total` and then use that to further narrow down your search scope and look for `Net Profit`.

```py
# Your other logics
text = unique_message['text']
try:
    i = text.index("Total")
    profit_beginning = text[i:].index("Net Profit:")
except ValueError:
    # Don't look for profit
    pass
```

You can further enhance the lookup by using a *RegEx* and catch the number only.

Comment: Hi @MohammadFS , the result of the search with the code was ```86```, I'm trying to adjust with it but so far I haven't been successful.

Comment: The `86` you got is the beginning position of `Net Profit`, use it like `text[profit_beginning:]` and find the first `\n` to capture that part.